# useParams for category of products

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, jsx, react-router-dom

I am new with React JS and I am trying to be able to call the list of products by their category. That should be done from the Navbar, but I could not sort it out. I do not know if I can use more than one parameter inside useParams and also how to use it. If there is someone to help me with it I would much appreciate it. Below is the code.

This is the ItemDetailContainer from where I call the each ItemDetail:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import Aimara from "../../Aimara";
import ItemDetail from "../../Components/ItemDetail/ItemDetail";

const showProduct = (varietalId) => {
  return new Promise((result) =>
    result(Aimara.find((product) => product.title === varietalId))
  );
};
const ItemDetailContainer = () => {      
    const [varietals, setVarietals] = useState([]);
    const { varietalId } = useParams([]);
    console.log(varietalId);
    useEffect(() => {
      showProduct(varietalId).then((product) => {
        setVarietals(product);
      });
    }, [varietalId]);
  
    return <ItemDetail key={varietals.id} varietals={varietals} />;           
};  

export default ItemDetailContainer;
```

This is the Navbar:

```
import React from "react";
import { Navbar as NavbarBootstrap, Nav } from "react-bootstrap";
import { Link, NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import CartWidgetComponet from "../CartWidget/CartWidget";
import LogoComponent from "../Logo/LogoComponent";


const NavBar = () => (
  <>
    <NavbarBootstrap bg="light" variant="light">        
        <Link to="/">
            <NavbarBootstrap.Brand className="mx-4"><LogoComponent/> Global Bridge</NavbarBootstrap.Brand>
        </Link>
        <Nav className="ml-auto">
            <Link to="/">
                <Nav className="mx-3">Global Bridge</Nav>
            </Link>
            <Link to="/AimaraRedWines">
                <Nav className="mx-3">Aimara Red Wines</Nav>
            </Link>
            <Link to="/AimaraWhiteWines">
                <Nav className="mx-3">Aimara White Wines</Nav>
            </Link>
            <Link to="/Contact">
                <Nav className="mx-3">Contact</Nav>
            </Link>
        </Nav>
        <NavLink to="/Cart"><CartWidgetComponet /></NavLink>
    </NavbarBootstrap>
  </>
);

export default NavBar;
```

This is the ItemDetail, the detail of the item:

```
import { Container } from "react-bootstrap";
import Item from "../Item/Item";
import ItemCountComponent from "../ItemCount";

const ItemDetail = ({ varietals }) => {
    return (    
        <>
            <br />
            <Container className="py-5 px-5">
                    <Item varietals={varietals} />
                    <div className="ml-4 mr-3">
                        <div className="font-italic text-center">{varietals.description}</div>
                        <ItemCountComponent className="d-flex justify-content-center" stock={5} initial={1} />                                 
                    </div>
            </Container>
        </>
    )
};


export default ItemDetail;
```

This is the Item

```
import { Card, Container } from "react-bootstrap";
import "./Style.scss";

const Item = ({ varietals }) => {
    return (
    <>
        <Container>
            <Card>
                <Card.Img variant="top" src={varietals.pictureUrl} />
                <Card.Body>
                    <Card.Title>{varietals.title}</Card.Title>
                    <Card.Text>
                      ${varietals.price}
                    </Card.Text>
                </Card.Body>
                </Card>        
        </Container>
    </>
    )
};


export default Item;
```

Comment: You must have your Routes defined at some place. You can post that to make your post much clear. Also state clearly what you want to achieve using useParams ?

Answer (score 3):

**For your question with one route param**

As it looks you must be having a Route defined something like this.

```
<Route path="/:varietalId" component={SomeComponent} />
```

Now when you use **useParams** to get **varietalId** you can do something like

```
  let { varietalId } = useParams();
```

**For multiple route params**

Suppose we have multiple params to be extracted like

```
<Route path=":varietalName/:varietalId" component={SomeComponent} />
```

Now we just have to do something like

```
  let { varietalName, varietalId } = useParams();
```

Comment: Thanks @shivamragnar but, how I pass that prop to the Navbar? I already update the code above. I want to be able to call the products by category from the Navbar.

Comment: Hey @JoaquinPalacios can you explain a bit more, what you want to achieve? So what i understand from your comment. You don't have to pass any prop to Navbar. You just have to give links like you are giving currently. The URL param that you want you can simply get using useParams().

Comment: Hi @shivamragnar fortunately, I did solve the issue. Thanks for your help and your time.

Comment: Hey @JoaquinPalacios congrats on solving the issue. Mark the answer as accepted so that people can benefit from that.